# apache url completion suffix

Tags: completion, suffix

a simple question. I've a file named xyz.php on the domain http://mybeautifulsite.com. Url is http://mybeautifulsite.com/xyz.php
When i type http://mybeautifulsite.com/xyz.php all is right good.
But if i type without php : http://mybeautifulsite.com/xyz I've a 404 error
What onfiguration is missing ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way webservers work. without the .php the internet browser is assuming that `xyz` is a folder with an `index.html`. So its interpreting it as

> http://mybeautifulsite.com/xyz/index.html

Comment: if i rename xyz.html ( or htm)  i've the same result (404). i know th configuration exist. 
For example : when i type on my wordpress site : 
http://myblog.com/wp-login
then :
http://myblog.com/wp-login.php  is running.
Thank you